# Using status code 500 for reporting unhanded errors

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, http-headers

I am using `header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");` in my php code to output internal errors, such as if there is a problem with a database query.

The process will be to log the exception & return the status code 500. I am using this technique because then the ajax requests error function will automatically detect this as a bad response and the `$(document).ajaxError();` will be triggered. Though this works, I am not sure whether this might have any negative impact on SEO practices. Can anyone tell me whether there will be any negative impact of using this.

Comment: I'm not a SEO expert, but as long as you don't rely your presentation logic on 500 you should be OK. I mean don't show some content using ajax as it's normal page and return 500. Say, something happened, come back again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using window.location to redirect the user to a different page which shows the 500 error. Since its a ajax request I can't force php to redirect it so I am using javascript to redirect to a custom 500 page. Is this what you mention that I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Quite contrary, this will make an extremely positive impact  on SEO practices.

Search engines encourage you to use proper HTTP codes instead of spitting 200 OK for the erroneous page. In case of 200 it will **index** the error page instead of just marking it to visit later.

Though I am not sure if bots ever call your AJAX routines.

Comment: Thanks for reply. At the moment I am detecting the status code 500 from my ajax error method & using the javascript redirect method to redirect the user to a error page. Once this redirect is done the header of the error page will be 200 since it was a normal redirect. As this would defeat the entire purpose of using status 500 in the first place. Is there any other way to this correctly.

Comment: I don't know to that deep, but it would be better to avoid redirects. Why not to use the same jquery methods? Aren't you use AJAX for the very purpose of eliminating page reloads?

Comment: yeah I am using $.ajax method in jquery. I am using it to avoid redirects but if there is an exception from the server side. I thought that it would be more appropriate to show the error in a different page. When I do that the error page has a status of 200. Since you informed me that it better for error pages to not have a status of 200. I am looking for a way to achieve it.